# SQL Date overlap avoidance inside of the CREATE statement using CHECK constraint

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am really stuck on this because I dont understand how can I check for possible overlaps in such cases. So this is the condition of the task:
Imagine you are the manager of a hotel that has a table in its database with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Hotel
(
    Room SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    Arrival DATE NOT NULL,
    Departure DATE NOT NULL,
    Guest CHAR(30),

    PRIMARY KEY (room number, arrival)
    CHECK (departure >= arrival)
);
```

So you can't leave this hotel before you've arrived. Now modify this definition so that no reservation can be entered in the table such as the Arrival/Departure date conflicts with an already existing reservation date. As overlaps count (examples):

- already existing reservation 3.1.-6.1. with newly booked  1.1.‐5.1. or 4.1.-10.1.
- or another existing 2.1.-6.1. with newly booked 1.1.-10.1. or 3.1.-5.1.

It also states, that it's OK to use selections from the Table inside of the CREATE statement of this same table, and use it in a CHECK constraint.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please see this:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT

Comment: Complete example, even including a maintenance window: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-exclude-beyond-unique/

Answer (score 0):

Before reading check the tutorial about triggers and how they work https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/

```
CREATE  TABLE if not exists Hotel
(
    Room SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    Arrival DATE NOT NULL,
    Departure DATE NOT NULL,
    Guest CHAR(30),

    PRIMARY KEY (room, arrival),
    CHECK (departure >= arrival)
); 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION register_new_insert()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  AS
$$
DECLARE
    r hotel%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN
        SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE Room = New.Room;
    LOOP
      IF r.arrival < new.arrival and new.arrival < r.departure 
      THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Arrival/Departure date conflicts with an already existing reservation date';
      END IF;

      IF r.arrival < new.departure and new.departure < r.departure 
      THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Arrival/Departure date conflicts with an already existing reservation date';
      END IF;

    END LOOP;
    RETURN  NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER register_new
  BEFORE insert
  ON Hotel
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE register_new_insert();
```

Comment: Why a trigger? And how would that avoid issues with concurrency?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) with existing arrival, depature columns and also with the new values, then apply the range overlaps operator (&&). (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1105ac8c71fd29a632f43bb3229aab5d));

```
create or replace function prevent_register_overlap()
  returns trigger 
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    if exists ( select null 
                  from hotel h 
                 where daterange(new. arrival, new.departure,'[]') &&
                       daterange(h.arrival, h.departure,'[]') 
                   and new.room = h.room
              ) 
          then raise exception 'Arrival/Departure overlaps existing reservation.';
   end if; 
   return new; 

end;
$$;

create trigger register_new
  before insert or update of arrival, departure 
  on hotel
  for each row
  execute procedure prevent_register_overlap();
```

As constructed these are closed ranges,both dates are included, see *8.17.6. Constructing Ranges* for creating other types.

Comment: Are sure this also works when concurrent processes try to insert overlapping dates?